# What is the formula for me to get a value at a certain point?

Tags: problem-solving

I have a two linear points : 400 and 1000.
At 400, the value is 150. But for 1000, I want the value to be 100.

So in 600 steps (1000-400), the value has to go down by 50(150-100). I'm not really sure where I should go from here and what to do with these values.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is the function/graph that you're dealing with a linear one?

Comment: Hello! And it is a linear one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If I understand correctly, wouldn't it be that each step would go down by $\frac{50}{600} = \frac{1}{12}$, so as it's going down, each step value would be $-\frac{1}{12}$? If so, then after $n$ steps, the value change would be $-\frac{n}{12}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [two-point form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) of a linear equation.  If $x$ is your input and $y$ is your output you have $$y-150=-50\cdot\frac{x-400}{1000-400}$$  Plug your points in and see that it works.  I left it unsimplified so you can see where the numbers come from if you read the article.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was some point formula but couldn't remember it at all T_T. Thank you this was def the answer. And thank you to you too @johnomielan